# Magento Invalid value for 'visibility' for a configurable products .csv

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I created a spreadsheet to upload configurable products.

For the different sizes, Visibility is set to "Not Visible Individually".

The visibility setting for the parent product is "catalog,search".

Magento import keeps giving me this error:
"Invalid value for 'visibility' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8".

What's wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento import process support only integer values in field `visibility` so please use following values in filed `visibility` your csv file

1. Not Visible Individually => 1
2. Catalog                  => 2
3. Search                   => 3
4. Catalog, Search          => 4

See here

[image]

Comment: This fixed the visibility issue @Abdul and I appreciate it.